# Is there a way to get a number from an image src url with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been searching everywhere and can't find an answer to my question. Maybe I'm asking the wrong questions...

So, my problem is: I have a blogroll that displays the latest post images, where I have sites and blogs from diferent platforms that I want to share with my readers, including WordPress.
Most images (thumbnails) are square but the ones from WP blogs are with multiple sizes. Analysing the image src, I was able to find out that replacing the last part of the url did the trick and I can make those images fit with the rest without screwing my site's design. :)

Example:

http://colecaodisney.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/casty.jpg?w=112  <---original image src
http://colecaodisney.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/casty.jpg?w=126&h=126&crop=TRUE <---edited by me to fit my blogroll

Since I don't have access to those images src, and with CSS isn't an option due to my blogroll works with javascript, I did this changes with jquery:

```
img = $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('?w=112', '?w=126&h=126&crop=TRUE');
```

The problem is that where is the number 112, that means the width of the thumbnail, isn't always the same number. My solution so far is chain some replaces for every new width number that eventually show up.
And I was wondering, and looking everywhere, if there is a way to write that line of code so that it works no matter what the number that represents the width might be...

Thank you for any help.

Comment: [Regular expressions.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: Often using regexps to solve a problem means you then have 2 problems. But in this case it's the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Regular Expressions.

```
img = $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace(/w=[0-9]+/, 'w=126&h=126&crop=TRUE');
```

This will match:

> w=(digits)
>
> [0-9] Match a digit
>
> [0-9]+ Match consecutive digits

Comment: I would recommend using `/w=[1-9][0-9]*/` instead of `/w=[0-9]+/` - a regexp on arbitrary text can never be too specific.

Comment: Note that the result of this will be to set the variable "img" to the modified URL - it'll be necessary to reassign the "src" attribute afterwards.

Comment: I got it to work with your solution, but had to make it like this: .replace(/w=[0-9]+/, 'w=126&h=126&crop=TRUE');

Comment: @OsvaldoCorreia Yes,i just saw that problem, i edited it just some secs ago.

Comment: Had to remove the "?" from the second part or the result would be 2 marks like that on the url.

Comment: @Brian You need to use like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vo6cf1k3/5/
BTW why downvote?

Answer (score 6):

Because `attr()` returns the given attribute for only the first matched element, to change (potentially many) elements I would suggest:

```
$(this).find('img').prop('src', function(i, src) {
    return src.replace(/(w=\d+)$/, '?w=126&h=126&crop=TRUE');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vo6cf1k3/) (kindly offered by [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1342440/brian)).

If you need to store a reference the changed images (as from your question), you can chain `get()` to return an array:

```
var changedImages = $(this).find('img').prop('src', function(i, src) {
    return src.replace(/(w=\d+)$/, '?w=126&h=126&crop=TRUE');
}).get();
```

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: `function(i,src{` to `function(i,src){`

Comment: @Brian: sigh, iPad really is not the tool for JavaScript/coding. :-/

Comment: This is a good solution, but I need something that works just in one line as the line I posted is part of a large coding that makes my blogroll.

Comment: @OsvaldoCorreia If you want to replace only that line, you can still use my answer.

Comment: If line count is a concern, move the call back to one line with this answer like so http://jsfiddle.net/vo6cf1k3/1/

Comment: And why are you limited to single-lines, regardless of where it's going?

Comment: Like I said, it's part of a large coding that make my blogroll work with thumb nails. And because I have another images src already replacing part of the url, the ones that came from picasa albuns, so I don't want to mess too much on the coding already there.

Comment: btw, on the jsfiddle examples, to work the way I needed, the "?" on the second part ('?w=126&h=126&crop=TRUE'), must be removed. In case someone needs this solution later...